# How do the best for Web Testing?

Tags: testing, web-applications

I have done to develop responsive website. Now, I want to test my website.
How do the best for test our website? For scope : cross-browser, cross-device, and other. I think its impossible to test one-by-one every browser or device, as far as you know the web browser are thousand and every operating system has different.
Please help to share any best method to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Check phantomJS and casperJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool where you can test your website for cross-browser issues.
http://www.browserstack.com/  will help you out in this. This will make you test your site in almost all kinds of browsers.

Comment: How accurate that tool do you think?

Comment: At least you can test your site on various browsers from IE6 to Others and will make you understand as to what attributes and properties are actually supported be it HTML or CSS and with that you can understand the changes to make.

Answer (score 0):

You need a testing service as provided by Browsershot : https://browshot.com/. You will be able to ask a screenshot of your website for many browsers / devices.

There is also http://browsershot.org but they don't seem to have service for mobile devices.